# Preserve empty tags using xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml()

Tags: python, xml, dom

I'm using xml.dom to parse xml documents and I want to preserve empty tags (like `<node></node>`) using node.toxml(), which instead returns `<node />`... how can I avoid the self-closing tag and preserve the original node as it was written in the xml?

Comment: Why is that needed? `<node />` is valid XML.

Comment: because my xml contains xhtml tags too (in my real scenario "node" is a "div")

Comment: Isn't `<div />` valid XHTML as well?

Comment: What python version are you using? You'll have to switch to a different XML library, but I need to know what can be supported.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.1 (anyway I don't think that a <div /> is a valid tag... it's not an empty tag by definition, it MUST contain child nodes)

Comment: can you use lxml or BeautifulSoup instead?

Comment: I prefer to use only native python modules... I'm afraid that I will be forced to inject a fake node to make my tags not empty :/ ...right?

Comment: The problem is you're using an XML parser to parse HTML

Comment: the content is a mix of xml tags containing html tags